# Django : How to manage database specific code?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, database-agnostic

I am using the postgres `unaccent` feature for a django project.

This makes my app database specific and I want to be able to use some others databases (postgres without with extension or others). In this case of course, I don't use `unaccent`

I would like to have something transparent for the user. I image my code should look like something like:

```
def get_objects(text):
    try:
        qs = MyModel.objects.extra(
            where=[u"UPPER(unaccent("name")) LIKE UPPER(unaccent(%s))"],
            params = [u"%{0}%".format(text)]
        )
        return list(qs)
    except DatabaseError, msg:
        qs = MyModel.objects.filter(name__icontains=text)
        return list(qs)
```

Unfortunately, if `unaccent` is not installed on the database, the DatabaseError is raised but the 2nd query fails with the following error:

```
 DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I've tried to add transaction support and to rollback it without any success.

What is the best way to manage this error and make the code working whether `unaccent` is available or not.

Comment: you have a syntax error. The `)` in the `try` block should be before `return list(qs)`. Now, `return qs` is being sent into the `extra()` as a part of the SQL statement, and it is failing.

Comment: thanks, i think it's fixed. This is not the real code... just something to try to explain what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

You can check `settings.DATABASE_ENGINE` value as follow:

```
from django.conf import settings

def get_objects(text):
    if settings.DATABASE_ENGINE == 'postgresql_psycopg2':
        qs = MyModel.objects.extra(
            where=[u'UPPER(unaccent("name")) LIKE UPPER(unaccent(%s))'],
            params = [u"%{0}%".format(text)]
        )
        return list(qs)
    else:
        qs = MyModel.objects.filter(name__icontains=text)
        return list(qs)
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The problem is that not all postgres db implements the `unaccent`